# My model is only saving some of the information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, forms

This is a simple rails form using CKeditor.

I'm saving the content, it appears in the Update.

```
pp params[:email]["body"]
"<br />\r\nheyyy<br />\r\nbut now i am going to save this past 9 lines.<br />\r\ncuz  that&#39;s what this is all about<br />\r\n<br />\r\nI am crazy like that<br />\r\nc<br />\r\ncrazy<br />\r\ncrazy c<br />\r\ncrazy<br />\r\n<br />\r\nhere is another line..<br />\r\noh@!!&amp;<br />\r\nfa<br />\r\nsdf<br />\r\nas<br />\r\ndf<br />\r\nasd<br />\r\nfa<br />\r\nsdfasdf<br />\r\n"
```

Then my controller goes like this :

```
@emails = Email.find(params[:id])
```

Then! After this is called, I type `@emails.body` in ruby-debug, and it outputs 1/2 of that! :

```
@emails.body
"<br />\r\nheyyy<br />\r\nbut now i am going to save this past 9 lines.<br />\r\ncuz  that&#39;s what this is all about<br />\r\n<br />\r\nI am crazy like that<br />\r\nc<br />\r\ncrazy<br />\r\ncrazy c<br />\r\ncrazy<br />\r\n<br />\r\nhere is another line..<br />\r\noh@!!&"
```

Why would that occur?

The attribute is saved as a string in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely storing it in the database as a varchar instead of text. Depending on the length of the varchar, it will simply truncate the data instead of return an error. You can easily change the column type in a migration:

```
change_column :my_table, :my_column, :text
```

Answer (score 1):

What sort of column is `body`?  Could it be that it's a MySQL `varchar(255)` or something similar that's just being overloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you called:

```
 @emails.save
```

in the controller ??

If so, try calling:

```
 @emails.save!
```

It should raise an error if something goes wrong.